# initializer list constructor in std::vector

Tags: c++, vector, constructor

I wanted to know how can the initializer list constructors be implemented if I want to make my own vector class?

eg:

```
Vector_Class<int> v{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

How can this type of constructor be implemented?

Comment: Did the answer help? Please ask if you want me to clarify something.

Answer (score 5):

You declare a constructor that takes a `std::initializer_list<some_type>`.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

template<class T>
class foo {
public:
    foo(std::initializer_list<T> Ts) {
        for(auto v : Ts) {
            std::cout << v << '\n';
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    foo<int> x{1,2,3,4,5};
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```